# Enable VM backup with wordpress instance deployment

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine, backup

Hi I would like to enable backup of my VM with deplyoed wordpress instance? Can you tell me the steps to follow?
I have started the backup service and RE only I am experiencing the problem Error (10017) "No appliances exist on Management Console"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.